# laravel 8 validate array input with axios

Tags: php, laravel, axios

and this is my request code ..

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
      'file' => 'nullable|array|min:1',
      'file.*' => 'nullable|file|mimes:xlsx|max:50000', 
    ];
}
```

and this is the html code

```
<form class='curd-form' id='form' @submit.prevent='curd_create("{{$model[0]}}")' method='post' action='{{$path}}{{$model[0]}}' enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input id='file' class='btn btn-success' type='file' {{$file_requires ?? null}} accept='{{$file_types ?? null}}'  multiple  name='file[]' />
    <input type='submit' />                 
</form>
```

now if i remove the validation everything working good ..
but if i try to upload excel file
i got this error ...

[image]

and this is the excel file

```
New Microsoft Excel Worksheet.xlsx
```

now this happened with any type of file i add to the rules validation
if i add

```
'file.*' => 'nullable|file|mimes:xlsx,jpg,png,pdf|max:50000',
```

i gat the same error to the same extension ..
and this is the axios code to submit the form

```
this.show_curd_errors = false;
this.errors = [];
var frm = $('.curd-form');
let formData = new FormData(frm[0]);
var add_or_print = $("#add_or_print").val();
axios.post(path+page_title,formData)
.then((response) => 
{
    console.log(response)
}).catch (error => {
    console.log(error);
    var error = error.response['data']['errors'];
    this.errors = error;
    hide_loading();
});
```

what is the error in my code ..
thanks ..

Comment: when you get the error? when you upload an excel file or when you are tring something else?

Comment: when im trying to submit the form upload the excel

Comment: why you do this? let formData = new FormData(frm[0]);

Comment: can you console.log(formData) ??

Comment: this is the console .. https://i.ibb.co/KX2BGCf/Capture.png

Answer (score 0):

You have Declare Mime Types As This:

https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/httpd/httpd/trunk/docs/conf/mime.types

this will work:

```
   'file.*' => 'required|file|max:600|mimetypes:application/vnd.ms-excel',
```

The **mime** rule, controls The file Extention.

your Excel file may be .xlsx or .xls

but **mimetypes** dosent care the file extension.

Comment: i gat same error https://i.ibb.co/TBSYdZB/Capture.png

Comment: what are your validation rules? are you using two validation rule for **file**??

Comment: is this happened with every excel file that you upload?

Comment: yes with every excel file or any file but im using axios to send the request